# Populating Python list using data obtained from lxml xpath command

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

I'm reading instrument data from a specialty server that delivers the info in xml format. The code I've written is:
    from lxml import etree as ET

```
xmlDoc = ET.parse('http://192.168.1.198/Bench_read.xml')
print ET.tostring(xmlDoc, pretty_print=True)

dmtCount = xmlDoc.xpath('//dmt')
print(len(dmtCount))

dmtVal = []

for i in range(1, len(dmtCount)):
    dmtVal[i:0] = xmlDoc.xpath('./address/text()')
    dmtVal[i:1] = xmlDoc.xpath('./status/text()')
    dmtVal[i:2] = xmlDoc.xpath('./flow/text()')
    dmtVal[i:3] = xmlDoc.xpath('./dp/text()')
    dmtVal[i:4] = xmlDoc.xpath('./inPressure/text()')
    dmtVal[i:5] = xmlDoc.xpath('./actVal/text()')
    dmtVal[i:6] = xmlDoc.xpath('./temp/text()')
    dmtVal[i:7] = xmlDoc.xpath('./valveOnPercent/text()')

print dmtVal
```

And the results I get are:

```
$python XMLparse2.py
<response>

<heartbeat>0x24</heartbeat>

<dmt node="1">

    <address>0x21</address>
    <status>0x01</status>
    <flow>0.000000</flow>
    <dp>0.000000</dp>
    <inPressure>0.000000</inPressure>
    <actVal>0.000000</actVal>
    <temp>0x00</temp>
    <valveOnPercent>0x00</valveOnPercent>

</dmt>

<dmt node="2">

    <address>0x32</address>
    <status>0x01</status>
    <flow>0.000000</flow>
    <dp>0.000000</dp>
    <inPressure>0.000000</inPressure>
    <actVal>0.000000</actVal>
    <temp>0x00</temp>
    <valveOnPercent>0x00</valveOnPercent>

</dmt>

</response>

...Starting to parse XML nodes
2
[]
...Done
```

Sooo, nothing is coming out. I've tried using `/value` in place of the `/text()` in the xpath call, but the results are unchanged. Is my problem:

1) An incorrect xpath command in the for loop? or

2) A problem in the way I've structured list variable `dmtVal` ? or

3) Something else I'm missing completely?

I'd welcome any suggestions! Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Counting `<dmt/>` tags and then iterating over them by index is both inefficient and un-Pythonic. Apart from that you are using wrong syntax (slice instead of index) for indexing arrays. In fact you don't need to index the `val` at all, to do it Pythonic way use list comprehensions.

Here's a slightly modified version of what stranac suggested:

```
from lxml import etree as ET

xmlDoc = ET.parse('http://192.168.1.198/Bench_read.xml')
print ET.tostring(xmlDoc, pretty_print=True)

response = xmlDoc.getroot()

tags = (
    'address',
    'status',
    'flow',
    'dp',
    'inPressure',
    'actVal',
    'temp',
    'valveOnPercent',
)

dmtVal = []

for dmt in response.iter('dmt'):
    val = [dmt.xpath('./%s/text()' % tag) for tag in tags]
    dmtVal.append(val)
```

Comment: Hi Ihor, Thanks for this. I'm a relative noob, so some of this is over my head. I'm going to look at it in detail, both as a learning experience but also because it may offer a way forward for some other items I'll need to pull out of similar xml files in the future.

Comment: I'm new to list comprehensions, so it's taken some time to understand this. I've looked at it in more detail, and this is very slick. Thanks again, Ihor.

Comment: List comprehensions and generators are powerful features of Python. I suggest you to take a look at two videos taken from [Udacity CS212 course](http://www.udacity.com/view#Course/cs212/CourseRev/apr2012): about [list comprehensions](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MvXxpU3wcLc) and [generator expressions](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qZVWbkE-Fg0).

Comment: Ihor, I just checked out those links --- looks like TERRIFIC info --- I'm all over it like a cheap suit. thanks VERY much for these links.I'd heard of udacity before, but had never looked at it. I'm like a kid in a candy store!

Answer (score 1):

`dmtVal[i:0]` is the syntax for slicing.
You probably wanted indexing: `dmtVal[i][0]`. But that also wouldn't work.

You don't typically loop over the indices of a list in python, you loop over it's elements instead.
So, you'd use

```
for element in some_list:
```

rather than

```
for i in xrange(len(some_list)):
    element = some_list[i]
```

The way you handle your xpaths is also wrong.

Something like this should work(not tested):

```
from lxml import etree as ET

xml_doc = ET.parse('http://192.168.1.198/Bench_read.xml')
dmts = xml_doc.xpath('//dmt')

dmt_val = []
for dmt in dmts:
    values = []
    values.append(dmt.xpath('./address/text()'))
    # do this for all values
    # making this a loop would be a good idea
    dmt_val.append(values)

print dmt_val
```

Comment: Hi stranac, Yes, I thought I was probably getting both aspects wrong, as I'm a noob at both XML and Python... but this project requires me to learn both simultaneously! It's fun, but not without challenges, as you've pointed out. I'll try this change as soon as I can, though I have to leave now for a meeting.

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain this:

```
dmtVal[i:0]
```

If the iteration starts with a count of `0` and increments over times, you're not actually storing anything in the list.