# How do I strip characters from substrings within a list generated from an XML xpath search?

Tags: python, xpath

This question is a supplement to an earlier question. If you need further background, you can check out the original question here:

[Populating Python list using data obtained from lxml xpath command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11962576/populating-python-list-using-data-obtained-from-lxml-xpath-command).

I have incorporated @ihor-kaharlichenko 's excellent suggestion *(from my original question)* into modified code, here:

```
from lxml import etree as ET
from datetime import datetime

xmlDoc = ET.parse('http://192.168.1.198/Bench_read_scalar.xml')

response = xmlDoc.getroot()
tags = (
'address',
'status',
'flow',
'dp',
'inPressure',
'actVal',
'temp',
'valveOnPercent',
)

dmtVal = []

for dmt in response.iter('dmt'):
    val = [str(dmt.xpath('./%s/text()' % tag)) for tag in tags]
    val.insert(0, str(datetime.now())) #Add timestamp at beginning of each record
    dmtVal.append(val)

for item in dmtVal:
    str(item).strip('[')
    str(item).strip(']')
    str(item).strip('"')
```

This last block is where I am having problems. The data I am getting for `dmtVal` looks like:

```
[['2012-08-16 12:38:45.152222', "['0x46']", "['0x32']", "['1.234']", "['5.678']", "['9.123']", "['4.567']", "['0x98']", "['0x97']"], ['2012-08-16 12:38:45.152519', "['0x47']", "['0x33']", "['8.901']", "['2.345']", "['6.789']", "['0.123']", "['0x96']", "['0x95']"]]
```

However, I really want the data to look like this:

```
[['2012-08-16 12:38:45.152222', '0x46', '0x32', '1.234', '5.678', '9.123', '4.567', '0x98', '0x97'], ['2012-08-16 12:38:45.152519', '0x47', '0x33', '8.901', '2.345', '6.789', '0.123', '0x96', '0x95']]
```

I thought this was a fairly simple string stripping job, and I tried code inside the original iteration *(where `dmtVal` was originally populated)*, but that didn't work, so I took the stripping operation outside the loop, as listed above, and it is still not working. I'm thinking I'm making some kind of noob-error, but can't find it. Any suggestions would be welcome!

---

Thanks to all of you for prompt and useful responses.  Here is the corrected code:

```
from lxml import etree as ET
from datetime import datetime

xmlDoc = ET.parse('http://192.168.1.198/Bench_read_scalar.xml')

print '...Starting to parse XML nodes'

response = xmlDoc.getroot()

tags = (
'address',
'status',
'flow',
'dp',
'inPressure',
'actVal',
'temp',
'valveOnPercent',
)

dmtVal = []

for dmt in response.iter('dmt'):
    val = [' '.join(dmt.xpath('./%s/text()' % tag)) for tag in tags]
    val.insert(0, str(datetime.now())) #Add timestamp at beginning of each record
    dmtVal.append(val)
```

Which yields:

```
...Starting to parse XML nodes
[['2012-08-16 14:41:10.442776', '0x46', '0x32', '1.234', '5.678', '9.123', '4.567', '0x98', '0x97'], ['2012-08-16 14:41:10.443052', '0x47', '0x33', '8.901', '2.345', '6.789', '0.123', '0x96', '0x95']]
...Done
```

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is: Don't create the strings in the first place.

Your problem is in this part of the code:

```
for dmt in response.iter('dmt'):
    val = [str(dmt.xpath('./%s/text()' % tag)) for tag in tags]
```

I'm guessing you used `str()` here to try to extract the string from the list `xpath()` returns.
However, this is not what you're getting; `str()` just gives you a string representation of the list.

You have a few choices to do what you want.
But given you're parsing html, and therefor can't know for sure how many elements the list will contain, your best option is probably using `''.join()`:

```
for dmt in response.iter('dmt'):
    val = [''.join(dmt.xpath('./%s/text()' % tag)) for tag in tags]
```

EDIT: You won't need your last loop if you use this code.

Comment: Thanks for an elegant solution that solves the root-cause problem -- an xpath output that wasn't quite right.

Answer (score 2):

Given your current data as `grps`

**SOLUTION 1 - ast.literal_eval**

```
import ast
grps = [['2012-08-16 12:38:45.152222', "['0x46']", "['0x32']", "['1.234']", "['5.678']", "['9.123']", "['4.567']", "['0x98']", "['0x97']"], ['2012-08-16 12:38:45.152519', "['0x47']", "['0x33']", "['8.901']", "['2.345']", "['6.789']", "['0.123']", "['0x96']", "['0x95']"]]
desired_output = [[grp[0]] + [ast.literal_eval(item)[0] for item in grp[1:]] for grp in grps]

print desired_output
```

**OUTPUT**

```
[['2012-08-16 12:38:45.152222', '0x46', '0x32', '1.234', '5.678', '9.123', '4.567', '0x98', '0x97'], ['2012-08-16 12:38:45.152519', '0x47', '0x33', '8.901', '2.345', '6.789', '0.123', '0x96', '0x95']]
```

**Explanation**

[ast.literal_eval](http://docs.python.org/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) is a safe way to do `eval`.  It will only work to eval datatypes (strings, numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, booleans, and None).  In your case it will evaluate "['1.0']" to be a list of length 1, like `['1.0']`.  You will probably want to take a look at, and make sure you understand [list comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

The other way to write this would have been:

```
desired_output = []
for grp in grps:  # loop through each group
    new_grp = grp[0]  # assign the first element (an array) to be our new_grp
    for item in grp[1:]  # loop over every item from index 1 to the end
        evaluated_item = ast.literal_eval(item)  # get the evaluated data
        new_grp.append(evaluated_item[0])  # append the item in the 1 item list to the new_grp
    desired_output.append(new_grp)  # append the new_grp to the desired_output list
```

**SOLUTION 2 - regular expressions**

```
import re
stripper = re.compile("[\[\]']")
grps = [['2012-08-16 12:38:45.152222', "['0x46']", "['0x32']", "['1.234']", "['5.678']", "['9.123']", "['4.567']", "['0x98']", "['0x97']"], ['2012-08-16 12:38:45.152519', "['0x47']", "['0x33']", "['8.901']", "['2.345']", "['6.789']", "['0.123']", "['0x96']", "['0x95']"]]
desired_output = [[grp[0]] + [ stripper.sub('', item) for item in grp[1:]] for grp in grps]
```

The problem with your solution, is that the items being iterated over in the for loop are not passed by reference, so changing them does not affect the original data.

**SOLUTION 3 - fix for your original code**

To fix your solution, you would do:

```
for i, grp in enumerate(dmtVal):  # loop over the inner lists
    for j, item in enumerate(grp):
        dmtVal[i][j] = item.strip('\]')
        dmtVal[i][j] = dmtVal[i][j].lstrip('\[')
        dmtVal[i][j] = dmtVal[i][j].strip("'")
```

Instead of assigning the balue balue to `dmtVal[i][j]` each time you strip, you could instead use the dereferenced value `item`, manipulate it, then assign back to `dmtVal[i][j]` at the end.

```
for i, grp in enumerate(dmtVal):  # loop over the inner lists
    for j, item in enumerate(grp):
        # Could intead be
        item = item.strip('\]')
        item = dmtVal[i][j].lstrip('\[')
        item = dmtVal[i][j].strip("'")
        dmtVal[i][j] = item
```

Or a better solution (imho):

```
for i, grp in enumerate(dmtVal):  # loop over the inner lists
    for j, item in enumerate(grp):
        dmtVal[i][j] = item.replace('[', '').replace(']', '').replace("'", '')
```

Comment: That code works, but it isn't the most pedagogical answer I have ever seen. Do we want this site to give people digital voodoo incantations, or to help the askers understand the solution?

Comment: @JosefAssad: right you are.  I am adding an explanation of both solutions.

Comment: Thanks sberry, for 3 good solutions. Thanks, @JosefAssad , for encouraging good explanations, it sure makes understanding (vs. cut+paste copying) much easier.

Answer (score 1):

This'll do what you need it to, maybe not the fanciest of ways though:

```
new_dmt_val = []
for sublist in dmtVal:
    new_dmt_val.append([elem.strip('[\'').strip('\']') for elem in sublist])
```

Tried to make it readable, it's probably doable in fewer, but more confusing lines.

Answer (score 1):

`string.strip` only strips leading and trailing chars. You may want to use `string.replace` instead. Also, note that, `string.strip` (and `string.replace`) return a *copy* of the string.

or simply use `''.join()` in place of `str` and forgo the whole stripping business completely:

```
val = [''.join(dmt.xpath('./%s/text()' % tag)) for tag in tags]
```

as a side note, you probably want to use `datetime.isoformat` instead of `str` too:

```
val.insert(0, datetime.now().isoformat()) #Add timestamp at beginning of each record
```

see `help(datetime)` for more options

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion about `isoformat` -- I'm going to go look at it right now.

Comment: I've added the `isoformat` option to the code in this script, but also added it to code in a related module, which is also collecting data from an instrument (no XML on this one!) - Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Where `xml` is the string of your original post... (I think this covers both in a way...)

```
from lxml import etree
from datetime import datetime
from ast import literal_eval

tree = etree.fromstring(xml).getroottree()
dmts = []
for dmt in tree.iterfind('dmt'):
    to_add = {'datetime': datetime.now()}
    to_add.update( {n.tag:literal_eval(n.text) for n in dmt} )
    dmts.append(to_add)
```

You can still order the nodes explicitly later - although I find this approach clearer as you can just use names rather than indexing (this all depends whether the introduction or removal of a node should be an error though)

Comment: Hi Jon, Thanks for this -- I've implemented the join approach suggested by @stranac above. The ast module looks like a sophisticated approach to the solution, but also complex, and I'm still a relative Python noob!

Comment: @RedSpanner We've all been "noobs" in a language at some point - I hope you enjoy your experience in Python